# pageblocksectionitems hidden on visualforce page load

Tags: visualforce

My requirement is the below two pageblocksectionitems should be hidden by default when the page loads initially and in the backend they will flip the FEE field value(not displayed on the page) to 5.99 then these 2 pageblocksectionitems should be displayed conditionally(which I already handled).

I have added 2 pageblocksectionitems in a visualforce page. But I want to display those based on a field value. How can I accomplish this?

Code snippet -

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="emvQn">
                    <apex:outputPanel id="emvQSpan">
                        <apex:outputLabel style="color:red">*</apex:outputLabel>
                        <apex:outputLabel value="If you have a non-EMV"/><br/> 
                        <apex:outputLabel value="compliant card reader, would" /><br/>
                         <apex:outputLabel value="you like to purchase an"/><br/>
                         <apex:outputLabel value="EMV-compliant card reader:" />
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="emvQOSpan">
                        <apex:selectList Value="{!ReaderOption}" id="ReaderOptionsId" onchange="Readerdef('select');" size="1" style="width:250px" onkeypress="handleKeyPressSearch(event);">
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="Yes" itemLabel="Yes"/>                            
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="No" itemLabel="No" />
                        </apex:selectList>                        
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

               <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="emvOpn">                
                    <apex:outputPanel id="emvOpnSpan">
                      <apex:outputLabel style="color:red">*</apex:outputLabel>                        
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Reader Type:"/>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                    <apex:outputPanel id="emvReadSpan">
                      <apex:selectList Value="{!NewSRSMPODLead.Reader_Type__c}" id="ReaderTypeId" size="1" style="width:250px" onkeypress="handleKeyPressSearch(event);">
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="None" itemLabel="--None--" />
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="EMV Card Reader" itemLabel="EMV"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemValue="MSR Card Reader" itemLabel="MSR"/>                            
                 `enter code here`           <apex:selectOption itemValue="Not Applicable" itemLabel="No thanks"/>
                      </apex:selectList>                                                
                   </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```